# VSCode - Change Menu Transition Property

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using "Solarized Dark" theme. It is flashing light when changing menu. You can get the idea by the screenshot. It is more flashy & frequent than seen on the screenshot (intensity could not be captured properly).

[image]

Is there any menu transition property where I can set something soothing color other than that flashy white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your `user` settings first

[image]

Then search for `window.titlebar` and find  `Window: Title Bar Style` and check whether is it is set to `native` or `custom`. Try changing it to `custom` if it is set to `native` and see if that works!

Don't forget to restart the vscode!

[image]